# Is there anyway for a Determinist to justify capital punishment as being logical?

Tags: free-will, determinism

Hello to all great philosophers here!

I've recently finished an essay and a few readings on determinism vs compatibilism. I actually have a few questions but my question is this : **can a determinist support capital punishment in any way, given that he believes humanity has no free will?**.

It seems to me that a determinist would believe that capital punishment can't be justifiable as a lack of free will would mean that humans are not responsible for their actions. Punishing someone for actions that they have no control over seems absurd to me.

I understand that some people would argue that concepts like "good" and "evil" would not dissapear even though we have no free will. But if your "goodness" and "evilness" were predetermined from the Laws of Nature, it would then mean that you had no responsibility in the first place. Does it make sense to punish "evil" behavior when that person had no free will?

Another perspective that I came across was from Bertrand Russell. It seems that he would argue that "evil" people need to be punished so that we can fix them. He would likely argue that people are responsible for what they do if there are no excusing conditions (Eg: An Illness or Coercion).
Although his ideas seem intuitive to me, it seems that his stand pales in comparison to the determinist's viewpoint that we ultimately have no free will over our actions.

Sorry if this entire thing seems incoherent, I just had a lot to think about and I would greatly appreciate any clarity to my question(s). Thank you!

Comment: A determinist does not need to justify it. Executions or lack thereof are predetermined, just as whether or not they or others support them, and just as everything else. It does not make sense to discuss whether it makes sense to punish or not punish, except it will get discussed anyway because again, that too is predetermined. The point of deliberations and justifications is making decisions when choices are available, but [Chrysippus's dog](https://iep.utm.edu/chrysipp/#SH5d) tied to a cart need not deliberate whether to follow because it will be dragged along anyway.

Comment: Determinism is not something you can believe in, support or use as a philosophical guideline. Therefore it is unclear what you mean by "determinist". You seem to refer to people who believe that they are externally controlled and therefore not responsible for their actions. Nothing can be justified by such an irrational belief.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notion that determinism means people are not responsible for their actions arises from a confused notion of "responsibility."

Suppose a car engine is broken.  To get it working again, you have to find out which part is responsible for the problem, and repair or replace that part.

We don't say:  "Because the engine works deterministically, no part truly bears responsibility, and so it is unjust to remove any part."

Instead, we say that each part is *responsible* for carrying out a certain function within the engine, and if it fails to carry out that function, it is broken and needs repair or replacement.  If all parts of the engine carry out their assigned functions, then the engine works properly.

This is related to the [credit assignment problem](http://www.bcp.psych.ualberta.ca/%7Emike/Pearl_Street/Dictionary/contents/C/creditassign.html) in artificial intelligence.  You have a complex system that sometimes succeeds at its task, and sometimes fails.  The credit assignment problem is the problem of working out which parts of the complex system were most responsible for each success or failure; how did the performance of each part contribute to the performance of the whole?

In a just society, credit is appropriately assigned to each person based on how they contribute to overall societal welfare.  Someone who does good for society overall ought to receive reward, and someone who hurts society overall ought to be punished.  That gives everyone an incentive to perform actions beneficial to society.  (What constitutes "societal welfare" is debatable - perhaps involving measures of average health and happiness in the society, among other things.)

Capital punishment could, in some poor societies, be justifiable under this basis.  If there are criminals who must be severely punished to disincentivize their criminal behavior and keep them out of society, but there are not enough resources to imprison those criminals for long periods of time, then it could be necessary to execute them.  This argument holds less weight in modern societies, where we can afford to imprison criminals for life.  In modern societies, executing a criminal is usually *more* expensive than simply imprisoning them.

Comment: Thank you! I think this answer and the examples you highlighted definitely gave me some insight to the idea of "responsibility" and free will.

Comment: First, we do not apply "justice" and "responsibility" to car parts, they are not moral agents. And second, even using them metaphorically only makes sense because we take ourselves to be agents, free to remove the part or leave it. If that too is predetermined even this derived shadow of "responsibility" vanishes. Indeed, there is no point to "oughts" and decision making they motivate, that empty talk is just there because it too is predetermined. As Wittgenstein pointed out, "do this" only makes sense when one can ask "and what if I don't?"

Comment: @Conifold we might not talk about justice with car parts, but we definitely talk about responsibility.  A dead battery may be responsible for the car failing to start for instance.

Comment: @Conifold I didn't say we applied justice to car parts, only responsibility.  Justice makes sense only when we can reward or punish the parts to make them work better, as we can do with humans; justice is when humans get what they "deserve," and what they deserve is based on how much harm or benefit they caused for society.  Secondly, in this I take as a premise that we want to maximize societal welfare - the "big ought."  Little oughts, like "you shouldn't commit arson," are useful in service to the big one.  Solving the credit assignment problem is *of practical use*.

Comment: @Conifold Where does the "big ought" come from?  Well, if two people already agree on it, or at least agree on some part of societal welfare, then they do not need to argue over that part; they can get along with the business of organizing society to optimize the part they agree on.  If they do not already agree, they must try to persuade each other until one or both change their mind, or if this cannot be done they must oppose each other.

Comment: The responsibility in OP is moral responsibility, you replace it with causal responsibility by equivocation. Even then, causal responsibility is grounded in token causation, but under determinism there is only one lump "cause", the initial state + evolution laws, and the malfunctioning car part is as much a "cause" as the rest of the universe. Only its relation to indeterministic actions of the mechanic single it out. The same goes for your "big ought" premise, it too presupposes agents exempt from determinism. A consistent determinist should reject the justification task, not fall for it.

Comment: @Conifold 1. When something goes wrong, the moral responsibility falls to the person who caused it to go wrong.  Moral responsibility is a type of causal responsibility; specifically, it is causal responsibility for causing harm or benefit for society as a whole. 2. When describing causation there is no need for a non-deterministic mechanic.  We can (theoretically) trace causation among clouds of interstellar dust with no human involved.  Your "lump cause" formally decomposes into causes among parts.  3. It presupposes agents, but nothing said they are exempt from determinism.

Comment: @Conifold Deterministic agents may make choices, react emotionally, try to persuade each other; it is simply understood that these words all refer to deterministic operations within the agents' brains.  4. "Justification" is a meaningful and useful concept, and an important part of what minds do.  As a part of what minds do, it is a physical process, since minds supervene on brains, which are physical.  A determinist should analyze the structure of this process, not pretend it isn't there.

Comment: Nope. Causal responsibility is neither necessary nor sufficient for moral responsibility, and certainly not its type, see e.g. [Sartorio](http://sartorio.arizona.edu/files/cr.pdf). And you do not need to *say* agents are exempt, they are for this argument to make sense, including the "formal decomposition". Any individuating aspect must be introduced from outside, for determinism provides none. A determinist should indeed describe how people *talk* about "choices" and "justifications" and explain why they can instead of redefining words to imitate what isn't there by his own lights.

Comment: @Conifold Let me give you an example of the "formal decomposition" I mentioned: Conway's game of life has a next-state function which causally derives the next timestep from the current one. *At the same time*, we can see that each *cell* is causally determined by the neighborhood of that cell on the previous timestep. No human is required to see this; it is a mathematical property of the game.  The next-state function on the whole grid formally decomposes into next-state functions for each individual cell based on its neighborhood.

Comment: @Conifold Let's now take a step back. You want to justify criminal punishment to a determinist. What does this mean? It means you want to present an *argument*, that *persuades* the determinist to support criminal punishment. Suppose that the determinist already wants a society where people are happy. Then all you have to do is convince him that criminal punishment causally promotes the society he wants. If he accepts that, and if he is honest, then he will be persuaded to support criminal punishment.  You deterministically present him your argument, and his brain deterministically responds.

Comment: Conway's game of life is a good example of fake token causality. No cell is *causally* determined by neighboring cells, the *computer* changes cell colors according to the preprogrammed rules. The "determination" by neighboring cells is an interpretative *convention*. And something outside of the game has to prop up this convention, there is no internal reason to "see" it this way, regardless of who does the seeing or if it is done at all. The game as such has many properties and descriptions, *it* does not single out any one in particular.

Comment: It is not that the "agent" has to be human or intelligent, but it needs indeterminism. If you want to cut up the deterministic flow into token causes even abstractly you need counterfactuals, "Y would not have happened *but for* Y" and the like. "You want to", "you should", "if he accepts" are devoid of meaning without counterfactuals, and we have no counterfactuals under determinism. The predetermined response to predetermined stimulus has no more to do with "persuading" than neighboring cells have to do with "causing" color changes in Conway's game. "It is there" posture is outside the flow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129560/discussion-between-causative-and-conifold).

Comment: `The notion that determinism means people are not responsible for their actions arises from a confused notion of "responsibility."` - I would extend that a bit: The notion that determinism means people do not have free will arises from a confused notion of "free will." The incomatiblist conception of free will is a confusion.

Comment: Re *" If there are criminals who must be severely punished to disincentivize their criminal behavior and keep them out of society, but there are not enough resources to imprison those criminals for long periods of time, then it could be necessary to execute them."*:  it doesn't make much sense to speak of disincentives for the executed.

Comment: @agc The disincentives in that case are for the others who know what the consequence of such severe criminality would be.

Comment: @causative, As currently written the quoted sentence's subject is convicted capital criminals, not all capital criminals.

Comment: @agc What is being disincentivized is the *behavior* of the criminals, not the criminals themselves. It disincentivizes the behavior that got the criminal executed, e.g. murder.